# Underdamped Oscillations of spring-mass system

Tags: mathematical-modeling

At what time has the amplitude of oscillation of a spring-mass system with negligible friction decayed to 1/e of its original value? Does this time depend in a reasonable way on k, m, and c?

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE! Do you know the differential equation of a spring-mass system with negligible friction? Do you know how the solution depends on said parameters? What have you tried?

Comment: You could quote the equation of motion of your system, defining $k, m, c$